# How to make a clear scribble effect with white color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, illustrator-effects

I'm trying to create a typographic logo using Adobe Illustrator, I'm trying to make a scribble effect and I know how to do it, no problem of doing that, it's very easy.

My problem is that the scribble effect becomes so dense that it looks more like plain text with 100% fill.

Please can you help of best practice of how to do a scribble in white color, so it appears nice and professional?

if you need an example I'm trying to do something like this logo:

[image]

Comment: If the goal is a hand-drawn look the answer is usually: draw it by hand. It's often so much faster (and ultimately, more authentic) than to replicate it in a vector illustration tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your sample is hand drawn.** It's not a filter or effect. The inconsistency and variation in strokes and curves clearly indicates it's not directly computer generated.

if you want to use the Scribble Effect in Illustrator you need to have text large enough to pull it off. It won't work with small text. After that it's merely a matter of playing with the Scribble settings.

[image: scribble]

Even with a deftly adjusted Scribble effect, it's never going to get close to mimicking the hand drawn logotype. It may get close in concept, but it will never be close in final appearance.

Comment: Well Scott, I know you will answer me and I know you will give a great answer as usually. I agree with you. I try to do it by hand, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are using white on white. Don't do that.

Your sample is white text on a colored background. If you squint you might describe it as "white text on a dark background," which is another way of saying "high contrast" or "large difference in lightness."

Make a layer/group with a solid dark background (color or black), then work with your scribble text on a layer above this. When exporting for use on a banner or site, hide the color background and ensure you export with transparency (e.g. PNG-24).

If I were to do the example, I would probably just work with black foreground color on white and then use that as a color stamp or alpha mask as needed.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I did that, but still the scribble effect is not so clear and satisfied as the original logo.